# Formatting SQL queries for use in Arcpy?

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.1, postgresql, enterprise-geodatabase, sql

I have to make an SQL query on a column having not adequat name "type_borne_id", I couldn't make SQL queries using arcpy.Select_analysis neither selectbyattribute, but when I use select_analysis toolbox in arcmap it works with the same column.

I wonder if I should add some characters, or what to do, to query this column normally? I remarked that this pattern of names "name_column_id" is vulnerable to this error.

Example of the queries that didn't work:

`arcpy.Select_analysis("table" , "table_copy"  , " type_borne_id = 23" )`
`arcpy.Select_analysis("table" , "table_copy"  , ' "type_borne_id" = 23' )`

I have tested with other fields like "id" and it works normally.

I'm using Arcgis 10.1 & ArcSDE 10.1 on PostgreSQL.

Comment: Please include your query so we can have a look. In general, remember that you need to put field names around double quotation marks, which means the query needs to be enclosed in single quotation marks (for example '"FIELD" > 10')

Comment: I find it helpful to build the query step by step; this is especially useful when you're dealing with values stored as variables.  It looks confusing at first, but you can always use a print statement to see how it turns out: `whereClause = '"' + fieldName + '" = ' + "'" + fieldValue + "'"`

Comment: Thanks all but i don't have problem in quotes, i have tested with other fields like "id" it works like a charm

Comment: This is a frequently asked question. Example: [How do I include a variable in the where clause of arcpy.Select_analysis?](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/27457/how-do-i-include-a-variable-in-the-where-clause-of-arcpy-select-analysis)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

All selections through arcpy needs to be quoted similarly to how you see them in ArcMap itself.

In ArcMap you would see something like:

```
"type_borne_id" = 23
```

You can recreate that in Python as well, in many different ways.

```
'"type_borne_id" = 23' # Note the single quote outside the query
'''"type_borne_id" = 23''' # Triple single quote (docstring)
```

The above two examples just show two ways. You can use escape characters and other ways as well. For more information, look into the [Select](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#/Select/000800000005000000/) help page on ESRI.

Answer (score 3):

I realize this is an old post, but for anyone else that comes across it. If you don't know how your input file is (shapefile, geodatabase, or file geodatabase) there is a function that will append the field delimiters ([ or ") depending on the input featureclass.

See http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/AddFieldDelimiters/018v0000006p000000/

For further details.