# Points in Polygon Count: Error with arcpy.selectLayerByLocation_management

Tags: python, arcpy

I'm working on generating some multivariate hexbins and am running into a problem with the initial step of counting the number of points (for the first variable) that are within each hex polygon. Here is the code that I have generated.

```
import arcpy

arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True
arcpy.env.workspace =  "d:/projects/scf/shapefiles"

hexBins = "d:/projects/scf/shapefiles/hexbins.shp"
points = "d:/projects/scf/shapefiles/points.shp"

bid = "BIN_ID"
updateField1 = "UCR"

with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(hexBins, (bid, updateField1)) as binRows:

        arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(points, "pointLayer")

        for bin in binRows:

            binIDstring = bin[0]
            queryString = '"' + bid + '" = "' + str(binIDstring) + '"'

            arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(hexBins,"CurrentBinLayer",queryString)

            selPts = arcpy.SelectLayerByLocation_management("pointLayer",'WITHIN',"CurrentBinLayer")

            getPointCount = arcpy.GetCount_management(selPts)
            binPointCount = int(getPoimtCount.getOutput(0))

            bin[1] = binPointCount
            binRows.updateRow(bin)

            arcpy.Delete_management("CurrentBinLayer")

        arcpy.Delete_management("pointLayer")
```

When I run this code, I get an error at the SelectLayerByLocation line.

> ExecuteError: ERROR 999999: Error executing function. 
>   A column was specified that does not exist. 
>   A column was specified that does not exist. 
>   Failed to execute (SelectLayerByLocation).

However, after running this code, I've double checked that the MakeFeatureLayers were valid (they are) and then I've successfully run the line

```
selPts = arcpy.SelectLayerByLocation_management("pointLayer",'WITHIN',"CurrentBinLayer")
```

I've tried moving the folder to different locations (testing for file permissions issues) but to no avail.

Amy thoughts?

Thanks.

Comment: You have a typo as well: `getPointCount` and `getPoimtCount` used on the next line.

Comment: Sorry, I changed some of the names from the original code. The errors aren't related to this. Thanks for pointing this out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax of your WHERE clause (`querystring`) is not valid. [String literals](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_literal) in SQL must be wrapped in single quotes, not double quotes. If you just want to fix it, try this:

```
queryString = '"' + bid + '" = \'' + str(binIDstring) + "'"
```

It is mostly a stylistic thing, but this type of string concatenation is fragile and difficult to read. The recommended practice is to use [string formatting](http://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#formatstrings) instead.

If you would like to use a more robust function that uses string formatting (albeit the [older modulo style](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#string-formatting-operations)) to automatically add the correct field delimiters and wrap string literals in single quotes, see [this answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/27473/753).

Comment: This approach yielded the same error. But I'll implement the function-based approach that you linked to. Thanks.