# Select and zoom script for ArcPy?

Tags: arcpy, select-by-attribute, zoom

I am attempting to make a simple select and zoom python script for my address points. Currently the script will complete successfully but will not select or zoom to the entered point. I am using two parameters that have been set in the Script Tool. Address_Number (Long) and Address_Name (String) which both have identical spellings/data types in Properties>>Parameters

Here's the code:

```
import arcpy
mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument("CURRENT")
df = arcpy.mapping.ListDataFrames(mxd, "*")[0]
addLayer = arcpy.mapping.Layer("G:\Layers\GIS_SDE.AddressPoints.lyr")
arcpy.mapping.AddLayer(df, addLayer, "TOP")
Address_Number = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0)
Address_Name = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(1
arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management("GIS_SDE.AddressPoints", "NEW_SELECTION", "A_NBR = %Address_Number% AND ADDR = %Address_Name%")
df.zoomToSelectedFeatures()
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is the Where Clause that you are supplying to SelectLayerByAttributes.

I would recommend that you try the technique used by @blah238 in this [answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/27457/how-do-i-include-a-variable-in-the-where-clause-of-arcpy-select-analysis/27473#27473) to [Including variable in where clause of arcpy.Select_analysis()?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/27457)

You could do something like this to use the referenced function with multiple conditions/fields, joining them with the `AND` operator:

```
arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management("GIS_SDE.AddressPoints",
"NEW_SELECTION",
" AND ".join(
    [buildWhereClause("GIS_SDE.AddressPoints", "A_NBR", Address_Number),
     buildWhereClause("GIS_SDE.AddressPoints", "ADDR", Address_Name)]))
```