# SearchCursor() fails to read feature class?

Tags: arcpy, cursor, where-clause

I am very new to ArcPy and Python in general. I want write a script to read attribute table from a feature class and merge some data from a csv file into the table. Right now, I am just playing around with the table just to make sure everything is fine, so here is the code:

```
fc = 'ShuttleStop_nextbus'
cursor = arcpy.SearchCursor(fc, '*', """ 'NextBus_nu' = '27837'  """)
for row in cursor:
     print row
```

(I have set arcpy.env.workspace to current workspace)

So I inspected the content of the feature class with

```
len(arcpy.ListFields("ShuttleStop_nextbus"))
```

It return 13, which is exactly the number of fields. Then I read all the fields with

```
fields = arcpy.ListFields("ShuttleStop_nextbus")
for f in fields: print f
```

Then, it outputs something like this:

```
<geoprocessing describe field object object at 0x24546980>

<geoprocessing describe field object object at 0x24546DE8>

<geoprocessing describe field object object at 0x24546E78>

 .........
 .........
```

Turns out the fields are actually of type Describe.

Is there anyway that I can query the table if all the above occurs? I still want to use the "where" clause of SearchCursor(). Let me know if I need to clarify something.

Comment: i don't what the question is. you want to print the values in the fields?

Comment: Yup, pretty much. So basically i can do something like this:

'cursor = arcpy.SearchCursor(fc)
for row in cursor:
 print row.getValue('Name')
'
But I still wanna use the "where" clause for querying.

Comment: go to the online doc, there's python code examples with most topics.    http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/#/SearchCursor/018w00000011000000/  don't use arcpy.SearchCursor, use arcpy.da.SearchCursor.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Confusingly, there are [two different types of cursors](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//002z0000001q000000): the "classic" cursors of Arc 10.0 and the arcpy.da cursors of Arc 10.1.

---

**Arc 10.0 - "Classic" cursors**

- When using classic cursors (i.e. [`arcpy.SearchCursor`](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//018v00000050000000)) the cursor object is an iterable containing [`row`](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//018z0000008r000000) objects. You need to use the `getValue` method to retrieve the data from the `row`.
- The second parameter for [`arcpy.SearchCursor`](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//018v00000050000000) is your `where` clause, so you don't need the `"*"` parameter in there.
- Your `where` clause is not set up properly, since Arc needs to have field names delimited by double quotes. To handle this with Python's use of quotes as string delimiters, you need to use the backslash escape character.

Here's a code sample with fixes applied:

```
fc = 'ShuttleStop_nextbus'
#List comprehension creates list of field names to read
fieldsList = [field.name for field in arcpy.ListFields("ShuttleStop_nextbus")]
cursor = arcpy.SearchCursor(fc, "\"NextBus_nu\" = '27837'")
for row in cursor:
    for field in fieldsList: #Iterate through field names
        print row.getValue(field) #Print value of this field for this row
```

---

**Arc 10.1 - arcpy.da cursors**

- When using the new cursors in the data access module (i.e. [`arcpy.da.SearchCursor`](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//018w00000011000000)) you need to pass in a list of field names as the second parameter in the cursor constructor. This requires some more work up-front, but the resulting `row` objects are Python lists, which makes it easier to read data when iterating through cursor rows. `arcpy.da.SearchCursor` also has better performance than `arcpy.SearchCursor`, partially because it skips unimportant fields, especially geometry.
- As before, your `where` clause is not set up properly, since Arc needs to have field names delimited by double quotes. To handle this with Python's use of quotes as string delimiters, you need to use the backslash escape character.

Here's a code sample with fixes applied:

```
fc = 'ShuttleStop_nextbus'
#List comprehension creates list of field names to read
fieldsList = [field.name for field in arcpy.ListFields("ShuttleStop_nextbus")]
cursor = arcpy.da.SearchCursor(fc, fieldsList , "\"NextBus_nu\" = '27837'")
for row in cursor:
    for cell in row: #Iterate through row, which is a Python list
        print cell #Print value of item in row list
```

Comment: +1, But perhaps the confusion with the asterisk was that with `arcpy.da.SearchCursor`, the second parameter is the list of fields you want to access, and specifying an asterisk means to list all fields.

Comment: Also, not all workspace types will accept double-quotes for the field delimiter -- use AddFieldDelimiters to take out the guesswork (see my answer).

Comment: Sorry that I come back to this question a bit late. So 1) Your answer actually works, but I just have to omit the single quote for the value (so it is \"NextBus_nu\" = 27837, instead of \"NextBus_nu\" = '27837'). Thanks!

Comment: 2) I'm not sure why, but arcpy.da is not available in my arcmap. I'm currently using AcrMap version 10.0.0.2414

Comment: @vandershraaf As I explained, `arcpy.da` cursors are *only* available in ArcGIS 10.1 and above. You do not have this. So you have to use the "classic" `arcpy` cursors.

Answer (score 4):

In addition to dmahr's great suggestions, I will just refer you to one of my prior answers which contains a function to help construct your where clause with the appropriate delimiters:

- [How do I include a variable in the where clause of arcpy.Select_analysis?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/27473/753)

This makes use of the [`AddFieldDelimiters`](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#/AddFieldDelimiters/000v0000004n000000/) function to add the appropriate (DBMS-specific) field delimiters, and also wraps text field values in single quotes.

Answer (score 1):

If you want the names (or other things you can get from [field objects](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#/Field/000v00000071000000/)):

```
for f in fields:
    print f.name
```