# Calculate area within Python script in ArcMap

Tags: arcpy, arcmap, field-calculator, area

*I am trying to calculate the area of a polygon within my Python script.* I create a new polygon from merging two together, and I'd like to add the area of the resulting polygon to a field in the output file. The polygon is stored in a regular shapefile, and is projected. Area preferably in map units.

I would have thought this to be a quite common and simple task, but despite a lot of Googleing I have been unable to find a working solutions so far.

I was planning on using `arcpy.updateCursor` to insert the value once it's calculated (there's only one feature in the FC at this stage), so easiest is if it can be returned as a variable. Any alternative solution that accomplishes the same task (getting the area value into correct field) will also work.

I have also tried the Field calculator from Python. Modified from the help pages I thought the following would work, but so far no luck.

```
arcpy.AddField_management(tempPgs, "Shape_area", 'DOUBLE')
exp = "float(!SHAPE.AREA!.split())"
arcpy.CalculateField_management(tempPgs, "Shape_area", exp)
```

Running ArcGIS Basic 10.1 SP1 with Python 2.7 on Windows 7.

Relevant parts of my current code looks like this:

```
#/.../
arcpy.Copy_management(inpgs, outpgs)
arcpy.AddField_management(outpgs, 'Shape_area', 'LONG')
fields = AM.FieldLst(outpgs)

#/.../

# Identify and search for shapes smaller than minimum area
where1 = '"' + 'Shape_Area' + '" < ' + str(msz)
polyrows = arcpy.SearchCursor(inpgs, where1)

for prow in polyrows:
    grd1 = prow.GridID   # GridID on the current polygon
    grd2 = nDD.get(grd1) # GridID on the polygon downstream

    # Update features
    if grd2
        geometry1 = prow.Shape
        geometry2 = geometryDictionary[grd2]

        # Update temporary features
        arcpy.Merge_management([geometry1, geometry2], tempMerged)
        arcpy.Dissolve_management(tempMerged, tempPgs)

        fds = AM.FieldLst(tempPgs)

        for field in fields[2:]:
            arcpy.AddField_management(tempPgs, field, 'DOUBLE')

        for fd in fds[2:]:
            arcpy.DeleteField_management(tempPgs, fd)

        exp = "float(!SHAPE.AREA!.split())"
        arcpy.CalculateField_management(tempPgs, "Shape_area", exp)

        # Append them to output FC
        try:
            arcpy.Append_management(tempPgs, outpgs, "TEST")
        except arcgisscripting.ExecuteError:
            arcpy.Append_management(tempPgs, outpgs, "NO_TEST")

    elif ...

    else ...
```

Comment: What is your output type? Shapefile, file geodatabase, something else? Is your output file projected or unprojected?

Comment: Also, could you post a little more of the code sample, in particular the cursor that you are using to do the update? Most likely you can achieve what you want using the `SHAPE@AREA` as part of your cursor to read the area; but the structure of the code depends on whether your area is in the same units as what you want to write out.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

There are three different ways to find and store polygon area into a feature class with arcpy: 1) field calculator, 2) "classic" arcpy cursors, and 3) `arcpy.da` cursors. Some of this is borrowed from my [previous answer about using SearchCursor](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/57096/searchcursor-fails-to-read-feature-class/57109#57109).

---

**1. Field calculator**

- When using field calculator, there are three different expression types that use different expression parsers. This is specified in the third parameter of the [Calculate Field geoprocessing tool](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00170000004m000000). When accessing the properties of the Geometry object using like in `!shape.area!`, you should use the Python 9.3 parser.
- The expression you had before performed a `split()` command on the result of `!SHAPE.AREA!`. This returns a Python `list` object, which cannot be cast into a `float` object.
- In your expression, you can specify the unit of the returned area by using the `@SQUAREKILOMETERS` flag, replacing `SQUAREKILOMETERS` with the units on the [Calculate Field help page](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00170000004m000000).

Here's the Python code I would use for this method:

```
tempPgs = "LayerName"
arcpy.AddField_management(tempPgs, "Shape_area", "DOUBLE")
exp = "!SHAPE.AREA@SQUAREKILOMETERS!"
arcpy.CalculateField_management(tempPgs, "Shape_area", exp, "PYTHON_9.3")
```

---

**2. Arc 10.0 - "Classic" cursors**

- When using classic cursors (i.e. [`arcpy.UpdateCursor`](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//018v00000064000000)) the cursor object is an iterable containing [`row`](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//018z0000008r000000) objects. You need to use the `getValue` and `setValue` methods to get the geometry from the row (as a [geometry object](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//018z00000070000000) and set the area value to the `row` as a float.
- Your output row is stored in a temporary scratch space until you call the `updateRow` method on the cursor. This saves the new data into the actual dataset.

Here's the Python code I would use for this method:

```
tempPgs = "LayerName"
arcpy.AddField_management(tempPgs, "Shape_area", "DOUBLE")
geometryField = arcpy.Describe(tempPgs).shapeFieldName #Get name of geometry field
cursor = arcpy.UpdateCursor(tempPgs)
for row in cursor:
    AreaValue = row.getValue(geometryField).area #Read area value as double
    row.setValue("Shape_area",AreaValue) #Write area value to field
    cursor.updateRow(row)
del row, cursor #Clean up cursor objects
```

---

**3. Arc 10.1 - arcpy.da cursors**

- When using the new cursors in the data access module (i.e. [`arcpy.da.UpdateCursor`](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//018w00000014000000)) you need to pass in a list of field names as the second parameter in the cursor constructor. This requires some more work up-front, but the resulting `row` objects are Python lists, which makes it easier to read and write data when iterating through cursor rows. `arcpy.da.UpdateCursor` also has better performance than `arcpy.UpdateCursor`, partially because it skips unimportant fields, especially geometry.
- When reading geometry, you can choose one of a number of geometry tokens, e.g. `SHAPE@TRUECENTROID`, `SHAPE@AREA`, or `SHAPE@`. Using a "simpler" token greatly improves performance compared to `SHAPE@`, which contains all of the geometry information. The full list of tokens is at the [`arcpy.da.UpdateCursor`](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//018w00000014000000) help page.
- As before, your output row is stored in a temporary scratch space until you call the `updateRow` method on the cursor. This saves the new data into the actual dataset.

Here's the Python code I would use for this method:

```
tempPgs = "LayerName"
arcpy.AddField_management(tempPgs, "Shape_area", "DOUBLE")
CursorFieldNames = ["SHAPE@AREA","Shape_area"]
cursor = arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(tempPgs,CursorFieldNames)
for row in cursor:
    AreaValue = row[0].area #Read area value as double
    row[1] = AreaValue #Write area value to field
    cursor.updateRow(row)
del row, cursor #Clean up cursor objects
```

Comment: Wonderful answer. Just wanted to say that as of 10.2, you would just do `row[1] = row[0]` as there is no longer an `area` attribute. You can also use the cursor as a context manager in a `with` statement and not have to worry about deleting anything.