# Using a different projection to calculate areas using the Field Calculator

Tags: python, arcgis-desktop, coordinate-system, field-calculator, area

I have a dataset that is in a WGS84_UTM projected coordinate system, can I force the Field Calculator to use another coordinate system when I use it to calculate areas using pythons `!shape.area@squareyards!` ?

My question is similar to checking "Use coordinate system of the data frame" in calculate geometry when the data frames projection is different; I would use this method but it does not have the option to calculate Square Yards. I could reproject the data to a new feature class, then calculate it and perform a join, or calculate the area in square feet using the data frames projection and dividing by 9, but since I will be doing this often the field calculator route would be the best way to go.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would try using cursors for this type of situation.  Take a look at [Update Cursors](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//018w00000014000000) and [SpatialReference objects](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//018z0000000v000000).  The update cursor can replace a field calculator process in arcpy.  Area tokens can be used to calculate area in another coordinate system, which can then be converted to other units.  Take a look at this [question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/57448/calculate-area-within-python-script-in-arcmap).

Comment: I was hoping I could do this in the field calculator instead of a Update Cursor, but it doesn't sound like it can be done.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use [`!shape.area@SQUAREYARDS!`](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00170000004m000000) (or in 10.2 to be more accurate, `!shape.geodesicarea@SQUAREYARDS!`), wouldn't that be sufficient?

Comment: I want to use the !shape.area@SQUAREYARDS!, but have that function calculate the area using a different projection than the one the feature class is using.