# Calculating shape area for polygons in different files using Python

Tags: arcpy, field-calculator, arcgis-pro, geoprocessing

I need to calculate the shape area (and possible the perimiter) of polygons for over 300 files. I tried to use a Python code but I am not very familiar with Python so when it returns an error I do not know where the problem is. My Python code looks like this:

```
import arcpy
from arcpy import env
import os
import csv

outputFilePath = 'outputPath'
sourceFolderPath = 'inputPath'


for root, dirs, files in arcpy.da.Walk(sourceFolderPath):
    for name in files:
        if name[-4:] == '.shp':
            arcpy.env.workspace = os.path.join(root, name)
            arcpy.AddField_management(name[:-4], "Shape_area", "DOUBLE")
            arcpy.CalculateField_management(name[:-4], outputFilePath + '/' + name[:-4], "Shape_area", "PYTHON_9.3")
```

I received this error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 15, in <module>
  File "c:\program files\arcgis\pro\Resources\arcpy\arcpy\management.py", line 3290, in CalculateField
    raise e
  File "c:\program files\arcgis\pro\Resources\arcpy\arcpy\management.py", line 3287, in CalculateField
    retval = convertArcObjectToPythonObject(gp.CalculateField_management(*gp_fixargs((in_table, field, expression, expression_type, code_block), True)))
  File "c:\program files\arcgis\pro\Resources\arcpy\arcpy\geoprocessing\_base.py", line 506, in <lambda>
    return lambda *args: val(*gp_fixargs(args, True))
arcgisscripting.ExecuteError: Failed to execute. Parameters are not valid.
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: I changed  `[name[:-4]]` to `name[:-4]`, thanks, good point. Unfortunately I still get error. A new one saying that `File "<string>", line 15, in <module>`, and `Parameters are not valid.`

Comment: Thanks @ahmadhanb, I change it.

Comment: can you please let me know the format of files you are using i.e shapefiles,feature classes or dbf?

Comment: I think what you are looking for is Calculate Geometry attributes please refer to the following link https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/data-management/calculate-geometry-attributes.htm

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you get correct syntax for [Calculate Field](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/data-management-toolbox/calculate-field.htm). It is best to include parameter names (for example `in_table='blablabla'`) instead of just relying on order/index of parameters:

```
arcpy.CalculateField_management (in_table="sometable", field="somefield", expression="someexpression",...)
```

For example you are providing `outputFilePath + '/' + name[:-4]` as field name, this cant be correct?

I never use CalculateField in code, so easy to get wrong. Try the much more versatile [da.UpdateCursor](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/analyze/arcpy-data-access/updatecursor-class.htm):

```
with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(name[:-4], ["Shape_area", "SHAPE@AREA"]) as cursor:
    for row in cursor:
        row[0] = row[1]
        cursor.updateRow(row)
```

Answer (score 0):

I checked first for one file the code here [Adding a new field and calculating area using Python](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/90685/adding-a-new-field-and-calculating-area-using-python) , then I edited my code:

```
import arcpy
from arcpy import env
import os

sourceFolderPath = 'MyPath'


for root, dirs, files in arcpy.da.Walk(sourceFolderPath):
    for name in files:
        if name[-4:] == '.shp':
            arcpy.env.workspace = os.path.join(root, name)
            arcpy.AddField_management(name,"area","Double")
            expression1 = "{0}".format("!SHAPE.AREA@SQUAREMETERS!")        
            arcpy.CalculateField_management(name, "area", expression1, "PYTHON")
```