# Error: Exception Raised on the "for row in rows" command line?

Tags: python, arcpy

I am comparing fields in layers. I have the AADT layer and AADTAnno layer and I want it to search the fields FLAG and TFLAG. For Example: If there is a 29C9 in AADT layer in FLAG fields then there needs to be the same thing in the ANNo layer in the TFLAG field. My code stops running on my for row in FRows command line. I think its because I'm not letting it know that FLAG is the field. Please help!!

New Code!!

```
import arcpy, traceback

mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument(r"K:\TASS\2 - GEO-DATA PROCESSING SUPPORT\MICHELLE'S WORK_ENTER NOT!!\Work Folder\Python Programming\Wayne's Tools\Abilene_Base_Map.mxd")
lstLayers = arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mxd)

flayer = arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mxd, "AADT")[0]
alayer = arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mxd, "AADTAnnoLabel")[0]

FRows = arcpy.SearchCursor(flayer)
ARows = arcpy.SearchCursor(alayer)

ffields = arcpy.ListFields(flayer, "", "FLAG")
afields = arcpy.ListFields(alayer, "", "TFLAG")

FList = []
AList = []

for row in FRows:
    Fvalue = row.getValue("FLAG")
    FList.append(str(Fvalue))

for row in ARows:
    Avalue = row.getValue("TFLAG")
    AList.append(str(Avalue))

matched = set(FList) & set(AList)

for x in matched:
    exp = "ID = " + x
    arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management(flayer, "ADD_TO_SELECTION", exp)
    arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management(flayer, "SWTCH_SELECTION")
```

Comment: lol is this file path for real? 'K:\TASS\2 - GEO-DATA PROCESSING SUPPORT\MICHELLE'S      WORK_ENTER NOT!!\Work Folder\Python Programming\Wayne's Tools\Abilene_Base_Map.mxd'

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: @blah238  Yes, it is. My boss wanted us to make sure people know what folder to not get into. LOL  I actually fixed the Listfields problem. My row in FRows command line is still not working. I'm thinking it's missing an IF. When I add the script tool to a toolbox in ArcMAP with no parameters. I get Error:999999????

Comment: Does the `FLAG` field actually exist in the feature class referenced by `flayer`? I also get a 999999 error if I refer to a nonexistent field in the argument to `getValue`.

Comment: So you want to compare FLAG and TFLAG values which are found in separate tables? What do you want to do if a FLAG value is missing from TFLAG? Add it to your Anno layer? I'm sensing a while loop might be necessary here...

Answer (score 2):

You have a typo/logic error in your second for loop. You reference `row`, but define `rows` as the iteration variable. By the time `row` is referenced it is out of scope. Presumably you should be getting a `NameError` with the relevant information to confirm this.

Also your `exp` expression looks invalid. There should be DBMS-specific delimiters around the field name (`ID`). Take a look at this answer: [How do I include a variable in the where clause of arcpy.Select_analysis?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/27473/753)

Comment: So, to fix this would I also reference the field in the same area and then add an IF statement?import arcpy, traceback


FRows = arcpy.SearchCursor(flayer)
ARows = arcpy.SearchCursor(alayer)

ffields = arcpy.ListFields(flayer, "", "FLAG")
afields = arcpy.ListFields(alayer, "", "TFLAG")

FList = []
AList = []

for row in FRows:
    for field in ffields:
        Fvalue = row.getValue("FLAG")
        FList.append(str(Fvalue))

for row in ARows:
    for field in afields:
        Avalue = row.getValue("TFLAG")
        AList.append(str(Avalue))

Comment: No, you would fix the typo. Change `rows` to `row`.

Comment: Now, I got it to get at least down to the SelectLayerByAttribute line. It's giving me an invalid expression. So I have that line of code typed out wrong right?

Comment: Please do not use the comments to put code. [Edit your question](http://gis.stackexchange.com/posts/59151/edit) instead.

Comment: I looked on Desktop Help and it looks like I have the SelectLayer typed right. I'm not understanding what I'm missing.