# How to pass expression to where clause in ArcPy?

Tags: python, arcgis-desktop, arcpy

I want to pass a user defined variable into a where clause

> Syntax
>
> SelectLayerByAttribute_management (in_layer_or_view, {selection_type}, {where_clause})

```
#user input
MTRsel = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0)

#put user input into where clause
arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management("Townships","NEW_SELECTION", "MTR" = + MTRsel)
```

I have tried many variations of this but it will not accept it, what am I missing

Comment: You asked this exact same question previously [here](http://gis.stackexchange.com/q/87828/753), which itself is a nearly exact duplicate of [this one](http://gis.stackexchange.com/q/27457/753). Try to avoid asking the same question repeatedly.

Answer (score 4):

I think the safest and clearest way to specify a `where_clause` argument is to use a triple-quoted string with Python's [`format()` method](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.format).

If the MTR field is formatted as numeric:

```
''' "MTR" = {0} '''.format(MTRsel)  # no quotes around value
```

Or, if the MTR field is formatted as text:

```
''' "MTR" = '{0}' '''.format(MTRsel)  # single-quotes around value
```

Note that the field name must be surrounded by double quotes if you're working with a shapefile or a *file* geodatabase (.gdb). If your data is in a *personal* geodatabase (.mdb), you'll have to switch the quotes to square-brackets:

```
''' [MTR] = {0} '''.format(MTRsel)
```

Answer (score 1):

at a first glance, you should use (if MTRsel is a number)

```
arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management("Townships","NEW_SELECTION", '"MTR" =' + MTRsel)
```

because python needs to interprete your whereclause as a string. You should also check that "Townships" is a valid name of layer (create by makeFeatureLayer).

EDIT : If MTRsel is a string, it should also be placed between quotes.

```
arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management("Townships","NEW_SELECTION", '"MTR" =' + "'"+ MTRsel +"'")
```

a good practice to debug this kind of problem is to print your whereclause using, e.g.,

```
print '"MTR" =' + "'"+ MTRsel +"'"
```

the output has to be a valis sql statement (you can check interactively with ArcGIS select by attribute.

Comment: still get invalid expression

Comment: this works arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management("Townships","NEW_SELECTION",'"MTR" =' + "'%s'" %MTRsel)