# ExecuteError: ERROR 000358 - Using a variable within arcpy.Select_analysis()

Tags: arcpy, error-000358

I have looked at [Including variable in where clause of arcpy.Select_analysis()?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/27457/how-to-include-variable-in-where-clause-of-arcpy-select-analysis) and while it is very similar to the question I'm asking I ran into the same issue after implementing its syntax. I feel like I'm still missing something related to how to implement the correct syntax for the below.

```
where_query = '"field_name" <= ' "{0}.format(year_range)"
```

I'm trying to make what into a geoprocessing tool that can be reused in ArcMap, but I'm receiving the following error. It looks like an issue with the way that I'm formatting the where_query variable, but I can't seem to get it right.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\ArcPy\mean_center_drift.py", line 19, in <module>
    arcpy.Select_analysis(in_feature, year_out_name, where_query)
  File "c:\program files (x86)\arcgis\desktop10.3\arcpy\arcpy\analysis.py", line 84, in Select
    raise e
ExecuteError: ERROR 000358: Invalid expression 1
Failed to execute (Select).
```

and here is the code in its current form.

```
import os
import arcpy

in_feature  = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0)
out_features  = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(1)
origin_year = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(2)
field_name = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(3)

for x in range(10, 140, 10):
    year_range = int(origin_year) + x
    where_query = '"field_name" <= ' "{0}.format(year_range)"

    year_out_name = os.path.join(out_features, "Years_{0}".format(x))
    mean_out_name = os.path.join(out_features, "Mean_{0}".format(x))

    arcpy.Select_analysis(in_feature, year_out_name, where_query)

    arcpy.MeanCenter_stats(year_out_name, mean_out_name, "#", "#", "#")
```

Comment: I realize that the general question and solution are the same as the post you linked. However, I'm using a different set of arguments and was unable to replicate the solution in the link provided. I was looking for some more specific instruction for my exact issue.

Comment: Take a look at blah238's solution in the provide link.  It is the more appropriate approach.  It not only takes care of field delimiters, but it also allows you to have a variable on both sides of the where clause.

Comment: Don't [cross-post questions](http://stackoverflow.com/q/31862747/327026)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks familiar! Depending on where your data is stored, the formatting of `field_name` in the WHERE clause will vary.

So, you can use [AddFieldDelimiters](http://resources.arcgis.com/EN/HELP/MAIN/10.2/index.html#//018v0000006p000000) to solve this for you.

```
import os
import arcpy

in_feature  = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0)
out_features  = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(1)
origin_year = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(2)
field_name = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(3)

path = arcpy.Describe(in_feature).path
new_field_name = arcpy.AddFieldDelimiters(path, field_name)

for x in range(10, 140, 10):
    year_range = int(origin_year) + x
    where_query = """{0} <= {1}""".format(new_field_name, year_range)

    year_out_name = os.path.join(out_features, "Years_{0}".format(x))
    mean_out_name = os.path.join(out_features, "Mean_{0}".format(x))

    arcpy.Select_analysis(in_feature, year_out_name, where_query)

    arcpy.MeanCenter_stats(year_out_name, mean_out_name, "#", "#", "#")
```