# Writing Where Clause for text field in arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management()?

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.3, file-geodatabase, where-clause

I am having problems writing WhereClause for my program. 
I am using 10.3 arcmap. 
My layer comes form a file geodatabase.

I have this code:

```
mlayer = arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mxd, "1415_LGA_SpatJ", df)[0]
fn_field = 'MAPID'
```

....function which creates list of values a_list

```
for each_a in a_list:
    whereClause = '"%s" = %s'%(fn_field, each_a)
    arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management(mlayer, "NEW_SELECTION", whereClause)
```

....

This code works when values of my field are numbers (field is long integral)

Now I need to modify the code and use another field instead, which has strings.
I get an error, invalid sql expression.

Could someone please help with updating sql statement.

I tried few things, but don't understand it really well.

Comment: SQL requires string constants to have single quotes about them.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
mlayer = arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mxd, "1415_LGA_SpatJ", df)[0]
fn_field = 'MAPID'
```

....function which creates list of values a_list

```
for each_a in a_list:
    whereClause = '"' + fn_field + '"' + ' = ' + "'" +  each_a + "'"
    arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management(mlayer, "NEW_SELECTION", whereClause)
```

Assuming it works it represents just another variation on [Including variable in where clause of arcpy.Select_analysis()?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/27457/including-variable-in-where-clause-of-arcpy-select-analysis)