# What's wrong with my expression?

Tags: arcpy, select-by-attribute, error-000358

I'm trying to have a user input a county in my tool, and then use that string to select from a layer of counties.

```
County = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0)
#Select county to clip
arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management ("W:/Homework117/Final Project -- B&B/Data/FinalProject.gdb/WestCoastCounties", "countieslyr")
arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management ("countieslyr", "NEW_SELECTION", '[NAME] = County')
x = arcpy.CopyFeatures_management("countieslyr", "CountyOfChoice")
```

The SelectLayerByAttribute process produces the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "W:\Homework117\Final Project -- B&B\PythonCode\FirstCode.py", line 29, in <module>
    arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management ("countieslyr", "NEW_SELECTION", '[NAME] = County')
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\ArcGIS\Desktop10.3\ArcPy\arcpy\management.py", line 7221, in SelectLayerByAttribute
    raise e
ExecuteError: ERROR 000358: Invalid expression
Failed to execute (SelectLayerByAttribute).
```

Comment: It looks like the text for `County` is not surrounded by any quotes, and it needs to be since it is a string.  I don't think the parameter returns the value with quotes.  It simply returns the value.  When you build your expression, you need to have quotes added to it.  It may be easier to do this by modifying the contents of the variable.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE! As a new user please take the [tour] to learn about our focused Q&A format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to get the value of your `County` parameter inside your query string

```
County = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0)

arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management ("W:/Homework117/Final Project -- B&B/Data/FinalProject.gdb/WestCoastCounties", "countieslyr")

query = """ [NAME] = '{0}' """.format(County)

arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management ("countieslyr", "NEW_SELECTION", query)
x = arcpy.CopyFeatures_management("countieslyr", "CountyOfChoice")
```

You could also try letting arcpy determine the correct way to refer to fields:

```
query = """ {0} = '{1}' """.format(arcpy.AddFieldDelimiters("countieslyr", 'Name'),  County)
```

Comment: Still has the same error. In my Parameter, I input the name of the county manually as a string, does that have any impact?

Comment: @SamKennard I have updated my answer with a slight modification.  Make sure your `query` is below the `MakeFeatureLayer()` and use the new `query` line I've added at the bottom

Comment: @SamKennard Good to hear!

Answer (score 0):

As Get Spatial mentioned you need to insert the variable into your code.  Try something like the following:

```
where = '[NAME] = ' + "'%s'" % County
arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management ("countieslyr", "NEW_SELECTION", where)
```

This is assuming that your field delimiters are correct.  For an explanation and help on that topic, see here:

[Including variable in where clause of arcpy.Select_analysis()?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/27457/including-variable-in-where-clause-of-arcpy-select-analysis)