# arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute not working with an integer saved in a variable

Tags: arcpy, python, arcmap, arcgis-10.0, error-000358

I have a long code written and this is the last little bit I need and for whichever reason it does not work. This is the simple code.

```
k=2
arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management("poligon", "NEW_SELECTION", "Id=k")
```

I tried a lot of different apostrphe, brackets and everything, nothing works. It says a column was specified that does not exist, `Error 000358`. But when I replace `k` with a number everything is OK. I'm at a loss of what is wrong.

Comment: Try `"Id=" + str(k)` as where_clause. Or [this link](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/27464/29431) can help.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  As a new user be sure to take the [Tour].  For questions that involve code we ask that you show us where you are stuck with your own code by including a [code snippet](http://meta.gis.stackexchange.com/questions/4312) rather than a copy/paste from your code and the full error message including the line number that results from running that code snippet.

Comment: This is because your query is looking for a field called k, which doesn't exist, hence the *field not found* error. @KadirŞahbaz is correct, you need to put your variable into the statement either with simple concatenation (as shown "Id=" + str(k)) or "Id={}".format(k) to insert the *value* of the variable into the string; either would work but I suggest that getting some exposure to format statements may benefit you as you move to more complex statements. Perhaps Kadir, you'd like to expand your comment to an answer.

Comment: @KadirŞahbaz Post this as a proper answer with a little explanation on string conversion, so we can give you the proper credits!

Comment: The where_clause syntax that I prefer is mentioned in @MichaelStimson's comment: `"Id={}".format(k)` I like that because it is so easily modified when using text fields to `"Id='{}'".format(k)`.  I also agree wholeheartedly "that getting some exposure to format statements may benefit you as you move to more complex statements".

Answer (score 17, accepted):

`Error 000358`means *"The SQL expression is invalid"*, as described in [Help - ArcGIS Desktop](http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/tool-errors-and-warnings/001001-010000/tool-errors-and-warnings-00351-00375-000358.htm)

Your query, `"Id=k"`, means that *"get `Id`and `k` (field) value of a feature, compare both, if both are equal, select that feature".* Since there is no `k`field in `poligon` layer, you encounter an error. Even if `k` existed as a field, any feature whose `Id` and `k`field are equal would be selected.

But you want to select all features meet `Id=2`. So, you have to concatenate `"Id="`string and integer `k` for where clause.

You can do it in different ways:

```
k = 2
m = 3

"Id=" + str(k)     #1 "Id=2"

"Id=%s" %k         #2 "Id=2" old style

"Id={}".format(k)  #3 "Id=2" new style

"Id={0}".format(k) # by index

## multiple variables ##
"Id=%s%s" %(k, m)  # "Id=23" 

"Id={}{}".format(k, m)  # "Id=23" 

# by index, m->0, k->1
"Id={1}{0}_{1}{1}".format(m, k)  "Id=23_22" 


"Id=" + k # doesn't work. In Python, you cannot concatenate string
          # and integer in that way unlike some languages do.
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I have already tried number 1 and number 2 which didn't work for me, but the number three i havent thaught of and it works perfectly.